# MacBook on takes long to establish WiFi connection

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

After upgrading  my MacBook Pro 13" Early 2015 to Mojave, it takes about 20-30 seconds to establish a working connection to my home wifi. It connects quickly, gets its IP address via DHCP, and I can successfully ping devices in my home network. Unfortunately it takes 20-30 seconds before I can ping any IP on the internet. DNS can not be the problem since I am pinging IP addresses.

I watched "netstat -nr" while the connection is being established and I can see that different routes are created. Just before I can ping outside IP addresses the following route is being added (192.168.111.0/24 is my home network):

```
192.168.111.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       18     en0      !
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you please edit your question, or create a comment giving more information about the wifi router you are using and the networking environment where this is happening?

Comment: My router is a pfSense setup running in a virtual machine and the AP connected to the main subnet is an AVM Fritz!Box 7490. What kind of information would you need about the pfSense setup?

Comment: Thanks for updating with your solution, but please leave the solution below as an answer and keep the question just containing the question! This helps show that the question has been answered and helps others looking for a solution to the same problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by myself and I feel a bit silly too:
In pfSense I had a DNS override set for "captive.apple.com" to point to 0.0.0.0 because I didn't want my Apple devices to talk to Apple every time I connect to my home WiFi if not necessary. After deleting this override it works fine. Sorry for bothering you with this.